# React JS: How to load only page related js, css and html on production mode?

Tags: reactjs, npm, build, routes

When we build the react project on production mode. It creates only one index.html, CSS and JS file.
so while accessing the project on browser it takes lots of time to load because of the big size of JS and CSS files.

So is there any way to load only the page related JS, CSS and HTML.
Or can we create page wise files while creating the production build?

Comment: I think that's what the concurrency mode is for. It is one of the limitations of ReactJS right now.  You may refer to this [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-intro.html)

Comment: It allows code splitting in production. Thus generating multiple js chunks in build

Comment: ok.. thanks.. I'm checking for this now.. can you please send the demo link?

Comment: You may want to check this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=00gQyXRL7KI . Jump to @5:54

Comment: Although concurrency mode is still not advisable to use for production since it is still in Experimental build

Comment: yes I saw that.. but still we will try if it works..

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using [`React.lazy`](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy). Which will load your component file only when your component is trying to load and render for the first time.

> This will automatically load the bundle containing the OtherComponent
> when this component is first rendered.

For example I'm using this for my routes like below :

```
[
        {
            path: '/apps/role/roles/:roleId',
            component: React.lazy(() => import('./role/Role')),
        }
]
```

You will notice separate bundle file is generated and also when you load `Role` it will load respective bundle file.

Comment: If it works for you then try marking answer as correct solution so following readers will get benefits too.

Answer (score -1):

I think the answer you're looking for is [Styled Components](https://styled-components.com/)